# Reference Parameters Address Automatically NOT passed

Tags: c++, reference-parameters

I have the following issue with reference parameters:
When we have a function with reference parameters, the compiler will automatically pass to that function, the address of any argument it is called with.
Example (with object):

```
class sample {
char *s;
public:
    sample(); // normal constructor
    sample(const sample &ob); // copy constructor
    ~sample( ) { if(s) delete [] s; cout << "Freeing s\n"; }
    void show() { cout << s << "\n"; }
    void set(char *str);
};// Definition will be excluded from here`
```

and we have a function with reference parameters of this class instance,

like:

```
void funtionWithRef(sample &kk); // declaration
void funtionWithRef(sample &sam){ // definition
    sam.show();
}
```

and one function with return object of type sample:

```
sample functionReturnSample(); //declaration
sample functionReturnSample(){ // definition
    sample sam;
    sam.set("test sample");
    return sam;
}
```

Now, when we do:

```
int main() {
    sample temp = functionReturnSample();
    funtionWithRef(temp);

    return 0;
}
```

It works perfect. When we put **temp** object as an argument to **funtionWithRef**, compiler pass address of that object to the function.
But **WHY** it does not work, if we do **NOT** first assign a returning value of **functionReturnSample** to the instance, but directly put that method as an argument like :

```
funtionWithRef(functionReturnSample());
```

Why is this different, when we are doing the same thing, and according to some books I consulted, whit **SHOULD**

**EDIT**

@user657267
This is the full example (source book: C++ From Ground Up, 3rd Edition, page 219-320):

```
class sample {
    char *s;
    public:
        sample(); // normal constructor
        sample(const sample &ob); // copy constructor
        ~sample( ) { cout << "s: " << s <<" ,Freeing s\n"; if(s) delete [] s;}
        void show() { cout << s << "\n"; }
        void set(char *str);
        sample operator=(sample &ob); // overload assignment
};
// Normal constructor.
sample::sample() {
    s = new char('\0'); // s points to a null string.
    cout << "Normal constructor: s: " << strlen(s) << endl;
}
// Copy constructor.
sample::sample(const sample &ob) {
    cout << "Copy constructor: ob.s: "<< ob.s << " ,strlen(ob.s): " <<  strlen(ob.s) << "\n";
    s = new char[strlen(ob.s)+1];
    strcpy(s, ob.s);
}
// Load a string.
void sample::set(char *str) {
    s = new char[strlen(str)+1];
    strcpy(s, str);
}
// Overload assignment operator.
sample sample::operator=(sample &ob) {
    /* If the target memory is not large enough
    then allocate new memory. */
    cout << "operator= strlen(ob.s): " << strlen(ob.s) << " ,strlen(s): " << strlen(s) << endl;

    if(strlen(ob.s) > strlen(s)) {
        cout << "operator= Larger memory of target object. Deleting current...\n";
        delete [] s;
        s = new char[strlen(ob.s)+1];
    }
    strcpy(s, ob.s);

    return *this;
}
// Return an object of type sample.
sample input() {
    char instr[80];
    static sample str;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> instr;
    str.set(instr);

    return str;
}

int main() {
    sample ob;
    // assign returned object to ob
    ob=input(); // This is now OK
    ob.show();

    return 0;
}
```

This wont compile, and reports error:

```
**error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘sample’ and ‘sample’)**
```

So it is copy/past of the code from  the mentioned book. You can check please.

However I figureout if I specify overloaded = operator arguments to be **const** like:

```
 sample operator=(const sample &ob); // overload assignment
```

Then it **DOES** work.
However, what is bothering me is, now when I have runnable code, I do not get why **TWO** times copy constructor is called.
I know it is called when **input()** function returns, and create temporary object, but I do not get why second time since, as much as I know (but maybe I am wrong) copy constructors are **NOT** called for assignment operations (same Book, pages 291-292), but it looks like, despite of that, when **return *this;** is called (when overloaded operator returns value), copy constructor is called?
So what is about that ?
Thankx

Comment: Because a non-`const` lvalue reference cannot bind to a temporary, I seriously doubt any book would tell you otherwise.

Comment: This is my understanding,  whenever the statement `sample temp = functionReturnSample();` is executed, the copy constructor is evoked (since you have not overloaded `=` operator). Thus the `temp` object exist in the scope of main. Considering the next situation when  `funtionWithRef(functionReturnSample())` is called it is different because the object `sam` created in the function is already destroyed if you come outside the function. There exist no valid object. hope it is clear

Comment: @Creator I managed to find the book, you are not at fault the book has an error. The assignment operator should be defined as `sample operator=(sample const &ob);`. Anyway, you might want to consider using a more recent reference, as modern C++ has changed somewhat and you might end up learning bad habits.